Integration over Hankel contour
In a write-up by Paul Garrett, he claims that he can apply the Residue Theorem to the equality
$$
\zeta\left(s\right) = \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(s\right)\left(1-{\rm e}^{2\pi{\rm i}s}\right)}
\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_{H_{\varepsilon}}
\frac{t^{s - 1}}{{\rm e}^{t} - 1}\,{\rm d}t
$$
( valid for $s \in \mathbf{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ ), where $H_{\varepsilon}$ denotes the Hankel Contour of ( inner ) radius $\varepsilon > 0$, to obtain that
$$
\zeta\left(-n\right) = \left(-1\right)^{n}\, n!\, \operatorname{Res}\left[\frac{t^{-n - 1}}{{\rm e}^{t} - 1}, t = 0\right]\quad\mbox{for}\ n \in \mathbb{N}
$$

However, I am not convinced that the Residue Theorem is applicable to this situation ( for the Hankel contour is non-closed ).
I know that the Hankel contour can be closed by the keyhole contour,  but this yields a different result when you apply the Residue Theorem ( namely, a functional equation for $\zeta$ ).
Thus, one would really have to prove that the integral over some semicircle ( which is what one gets when integrating the quantity
$$
t^{-k-1}\left({\rm e}^{t} - 1\right)\quad\mbox{over}\quad H_{\varepsilon},
$$
since the horizontal parts of $H_{\varepsilon}$ directly above and below the real line in the complex plane cancel ) equates to the integral over the whole circle around $0$. This I don't see.

Thank you very much in advance for your help !. Maybe I'm just missing a trivial point.

A quick note: my own use of "Hankel contour" and "keyhole contour" is that the terms are interchangeable, and both refer to closed contours... Yes, there are complications in formulaic descriptions of the out-and-in paths "just above/below" the real axis, and so on... :)

But they really calculate different things, right? The keyhole contour integral picks up all the poles $2\pi i k$, $k \neq 0$ and the Hankel contour only picks up the pole at $z = 0$.

This got too long for a comment I am a bit too uncertain to sell it as an answer...
I think you could use instead of the Hankel contour with a semicircle a slightly modified Hankel contour where the circle-part of it is more than a semi-circle. For example that the circle part is $\gamma_\varepsilon\colon [0, 1]\to\mathbb C,\ t\mapsto \varepsilon e^{2\pi i g(t)}$ with $g(t)=(1-2\varepsilon)t+\varepsilon$, so that instead of using a semi-circle you use a circle up to a piece of angle $4\pi\varepsilon$ cut out on the right side ($\varepsilon \leq \frac 1 4$). We set $\eta_\varepsilon\colon [0, 1]\to\mathbb C, t\mapsto \varepsilon e^{2\pi i (2t\varepsilon-\varepsilon)}$ as the remaining part of the circle. Now we split the integral:
$$
\int_{\gamma_\varepsilon} = \int_{\partial B_\varepsilon(0)} - \int_{\partial \eta_\varepsilon}
$$
The integral $\int_{\partial B_\varepsilon(0)}$ is constant due to the residue theorem and $\int_{\eta_\varepsilon}$ goes to $0$ as $\varepsilon\to 0$ as this path shrinks to a point.
You can probably argue that the rays coming from/going to $\infty$ still cancel each other out (although now the don't go right onto the $y$-axis but get closer as $\varepsilon$ shrinks).
This isn't well thought out but it was too long for the comment section...

Thank you very much! I have thought in that direction - what would be really helpful for me is if you could sketch why the integral over $\eta_{\varepsilon}$ should convergent to $0$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$, since the integrand contains negative powers of the integration variable.

@cxrlo Indeed this lacks justification! In the case above $\eta_\varepsilon$ decreases its angle linearly in $\varepsilon$. But we should be able to replace $h(t)=2t\varepsilon-\varepsilon$ with some function $t\mapsto h(t)$ having exponential decay in $\varepsilon$ or something faster. Then the length $L(\eta_\varepsilon)$ decreases faster than the maximum of the integrand on $\eta_\varepsilon([0,1])$ can grow. I think this could safe us, right?

I will try to write something up. Thank you!
